# icalendar event timezone not matching time with user timezone

Tags: php, outlook, timezone, icalendar

I am sending event to MS outlook through mail, But Event time is different with what i have send.

I Also want to support icalender event for all Application like MS Outlook, Google Calendar ..etc

Any good resource or api for implement icalendar event then let me know.
e.g

Sending :

```
Start Time : 12:40 P.M.
End Time   : 01:00 P.M.
```

At User end, Outlook shows event after 1 hour.

```
Start Time : 01:40 P.M.
End Time   : 02:00 P.M.
```

I want the same result which i am sending.

Below is my icalendar code.

```
$ical = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
        'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
        'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
        'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
        'TZID:'.date_default_timezone_get() . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:20091101T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .  
        'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
        'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
        'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
        'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
        'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
        'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART;TZID="'.date_default_timezone_get().'":'.date("Ymd", strtotime($startTime))."T".date("His", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
        'DTEND;TZID="'.date_default_timezone_get().'":'.date("Ymd", strtotime($endTime))."T".date("His", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
        'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
        'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
        'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
        'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
        'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
        'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
        'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
        'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
```

Comment: Try to create a new appointment in Outlook and then save it as iCalendar file. Then compare with your own file. Thus, you will be able to find the difference.

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

What is in your `TZID` parameter needs to match what is in the `TZID` in the `VTIMEZONE` object.

Comment: I want the same result what i am sending then what timezone i should set?. Without timezone should we send event?

Comment: Well right now you set it to `Eastern Time` for the property, and the result of `date_default_timezone_get()` for the parameter. This is wrong. i don't know what you're asking.

Comment: i have updated the code with same time zone with  date_default_timezone_get(). But i want to know that should i get the same time what i am sending e.g Start Time : 12:40 PM and End Time   : 01:00 P.M. i want the same as i have sent in calendar.

Comment: Well, what's the timezone you are sending and what's the timezone outlook is in?

Comment: Timezone Europe/London. Can you suggest me any library that will support event for all outlook like MS outlook, google .etc?

Comment: Well I'm the author for [sabre/vobject](http://sabre.io/vobject/), which works well for me =)

Comment: If i don't pass timezone tzid and also in DTSTART and DTEND then  what will happen?

Comment: If you don't follow the standard, then anything can happen. There's no rules in these standards that tell implementors how to handle mistakes.